# foreground bash script putting itself in background

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having a bash script whose behaviour is roughly.

```
#!/bin/bash
if some_condition ; then
    echo please enter some integer
    read a
else
    a=3
fi

# here 'd like to switch in the background
while true ; do
    echo beep
    sleep $a
done
```

So the script prompts for an input an then performs some background tasks.

At the moment I start the script, answer all questions / prompts, that might show up,  press `CTRL-Z` and type `bg`.

Then whenever I want the script to stop I type

```
fg ; CTRL-C
```

Can I do this programmatically (putting it to background) from within the same script.

Stopping will always be a manual step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the loop in a subshell which you run in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
if some_condition ; then
    echo please enter some integer
    read a
else
    a=3
fi


(while true ; do
    echo beep
    sleep $a
done) &
```

Comment: yes, that's true. I just wanted to avoid creating another process. I also have to be able to kill the process easily. 
At the moment I just type `fg ; CTRL-C`
so basically I liked seeing the process with `jobs`

Comment: will wait to see whether there is another answer. If not your solution might work with adding some code to save the process id like `echo $! > $0.pid` (in my case the script located in the current working directory) and an option to call the script to kill the previously called background task. Would still prefer if the command stays visible for `jobs`

Comment: No other answer.

I will go with your approach. to make it usable in my context I save the pid in a pid file, add a status and a stop option to my command as the task doesn't show up anymore in the jobs list of the current terminal.

I could post my code just don't know where, as code in comments is reasonable.
Shall I just add the modified answer to my question?

Comment: @gelonida if you happen to still have the code, I would post it as an answer to your own question.